# AngularJS $http request object for another request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Sorry for the confusing title, basically I have a json file that looks like this that points to other locations:

```
{
  "link": [
    {
      "href": "some-external-resource",
      "title": "services-path"
    }
  ]
}
```

My real problem is getting the href of the object to not load asynchronously into the Angular service. The following is my request to the above json file:

```
var servicesPath = $http({
    url: 'resource-directory.json',
    method: "GET"
    }).success(function(data){
        return $filter('filter')(data.link, {title: "services-path"})[0].href;
    });
    console.log(servicesPath);
```

I know what is being returned is what I want, but the console log returns the standard "then, catch, finally, success, error" object functions, meaning the data isn't there when I need it. How can I manipulate my request so the variable contains the information?

Comment: Since `servicesPath` is a promise, it won't actually be the value you want. You have access to the value in `success`, so use it there.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard You're 100% right, I completely overlooked that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an async call, the value would be returned when the call is finished (successfully)

```
$http({
    url: 'resource-directory.json',
    method: "GET"
}).success(function(data){
    console.log('response data', data);
    var theHref = $filter('filter')(data.link, {title: "services-path"})[0].href;
    console.log('theHref', theHref); // value shows here
}).error(function(errorResp){
    console.log('error');
});
```